# OpenCV in iOS: Class VideoWriter is implemented in both AutoLoop.framework and Runner.app. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, opencv

I have an ios app that uses opencv and some other libraries. When running it, I see a log:

`(lldb) objc[536]: Class VideoWriter is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AutoLoop.framework/AutoLoop (0x1f897bd48) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6AF089E9-121C-41B4-8706-3F63E9F39090/Runner.app/Runner (0x1057a7888). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

Surely, I can do nothing with `AutoLoop.framework`. But for the `Runner.app/Runner` (which is indeed the name of my app since I am using Flutter), I hope I can change it. However, I have searched through all my code and see I do not define `VideoWriter` by myself. With more searching, it seems the OpenCV defines that (please correct me if I am wrong!). The clue is: At `opencv2.framework/Modules/opencv2.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface` I see -

```
...
extension VideoWriter {
  @nonobjc public convenience init(filename: Swift.String, fourcc: Swift.Int32, fps: Swift.Double, frameSize: opencv2.Size2i, params: [Swift.Int32])
}
...
```

So I guess that is where `VideoWriter` comes from.

I *do not need* the `videoio` submodule of OpenCV, so I am happy to remove it if I can. Indeed, since I link against `opencv2.framework` and do not use it, it should be already stripped out and I am not sure why it is still there.

Question:

1. Does that conflict really comes from OpenCV? Or I made a wrong conclusion?
2. What to do to resolve the conflict?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you,and I finally use `CocoaPods` to import OpenCV, it fix the problem

Comment: Thanks. But cocoapod does not have latest opencv and I need that (old opencv has a big bug)

Comment: If there is no other ways, maybe you can package the latest OpenCV version by CocoaPods and import it.

Comment: I guess it is a problem of latest opencv instead of cocoapods? I do use cocoapods to import the opencv framework

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that it's a naming conflict of OpenCV. I build the framework locally without opencv.videoio module and the warning is gone.

Just clone github.com/opencv/opencv repo and use its scripts for building:

```
python3 platforms/apple/build_xcframework.py --out ./build_xcframework3 --without videoio --iphoneos_archs arm64 --iphonesimulator_archs arm64 --build_only_specified_archs
```

It might be tricky if you want to use the local xcframework in podspec. And it also needs some effort to write a Pacakage.swift.

I just manually imported the opencv2.xcframework and added some builtin frameworks such as `Accelerate` `CoreGraphics` `CoreImage` `CoreMedia` into the `Link Binary With Libraries` of project settings.

Comment: Thanks! But building locally seems not very easy given all those dependencies etc (I have tried last time)

Comment: I just used the default script without further modification recently. Maybe there had been some updates on the lastest master?