# What is iOS's `AutoLoop.framework` and when are we using it?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am facing [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490727/opencv-in-ios-class-videowriter-is-implemented-in-both-autoloop-framework-and-r) relating AutoLoop.framework. However, I do not know what is that, and a Google search also does not tell me much about it (even seems no apple doc).

Thus, I wonder what is `AutoLoop.framework`, and moreover, which framework(s) are using it? Thanks for any suggestions!